# Lower android version support of mvvmcross

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm new to mvvmcross. I read the introduction video and preparing with my project.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NihmK6R9r4s

My Question is, at the video, mvvmcross (current version 4.1.6) supports android version 5. I planned to support minimal android version to 4.3. So, what configure should I do to make mvvmcross to support android version lower than 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally you would want to set your `android:minSdkVersion` to the lowest API level you want to support. You would set your `android:targetSdkVersion` to the platform you intend to target. You would then set your `Target Framework` to the highest level of APIs your application needs. I typically recommend checking out the Android dashboard to see percentages of the market:

https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

These values can be expressed here:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="integer"
          android:targetSdkVersion="integer"
          android:maxSdkVersion="integer" />
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

There are also docs on the Xamarin.Android specifics here:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/understanding_android_api_levels/

Misc: http://redth.codes/such-android-api-levels-much-confuse-wow/

Comment: Thank you! I'd have to check the xamarin guide first.